# Shimano 105 5800 mech compatibilty with 5700 shifters

Tags: shimano, shifter, cassette, derailleur-rear

I have purchased a Shimano 105 5800 11 Speed Cassette 11-32, 116 link chain (CN- HG600-11) and longer-caged 'GS' rear derailleur (RD-5800-GS) to replace my original 105 10 speed 5700 series mech. Can I still use my original 105 5700 shifter?

Answer (score 1):

No -- you need to match the number of speeds on the cassette and the number of speeds of the shifter. The 11 speed shifters are [designed to use dyna-sys cable pull](http://velonews.competitor.com/2014/07/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-1011-speed-compatibility_337803) (which is different than the 10 speed road cable pull; its the same as 10 speed mountain) as well.

I'd recommend picking up either {a 10 speed road or 7-9 speed Shimano rear derailleur and a 10 speed cassette} or the 11 speed Shimano road shifters. The former (e.g. a 9 speed Deore RD and a 10 speed cassette) is likely going to be *much* cheaper.